# Difference Between Microcontrollers/Embedded Systems and Operating Systems?

Tags: embedded-systems, software

Wrapping up last year of school. I'm a Computer Science/Computer Engineering double major, and I've been given the chance to take either Embedded Systems or Operating Systems if I so choose.

The thing is, I'm not sure *if* that is the right choice. I want to know the basics and functioning of embedded systems (of course), but I also know that embedded systems often times interact and deal with operating systems. So I'm not sure if I pick just one course or do both of them.

Here is the course description for Embedded Systems:

"*This course is an introduction to microcontroller design that covers both theoretical and experimental concepts. Students will gain a comprehensive understanding of microcontroller architecture, including the CPU architecture, instruction set, interface with target board, testing, and program development using the structured assembly preprocessor. Additionally, students will explore concepts such as interrupts and interrupt timing, analog-to-digital conversion, and programming of peripheral chips. The course will emphasize engineering design subject to realistic constraints, covering applications in areas such as energy conservation, biomedical instrumentation, space science, computer architectures, and robotics. The course will culminate in a microcontroller-based project that students will design, build, test, and document in the laboratory*."

Here is the course description for Operating Systems:

"*This course provides an in-depth exploration of operating systems and their significance in different types of computer systems. Students will learn about the principles of multiprogramming and delve into various algorithms used for resource allocation. In addition, the course covers multiple-computer systems, enabling students to gain an understanding of how multiple computers interact within a networked environment. Through practical assignments and hands-on experience, students will develop their skills in operating system design and management, and will gain a comprehensive understanding of how operating systems work and their role in modern computer systems.*"

Comment: `Microcontrollers, Embedded System and Operating System` is like `cherries, cherry cake and cherry cake recipe`

Comment: a microcontroller is an IC ... embedded system is a computer system that does not present a desktop ... operating system is software that allows a MCU/CPU to interact with its peripherals

Comment: I think I get it, but could you clarify more @jsotola?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you mean.